# Proving the composition of a symmetric relation is commutative

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, relations, symmetry

How can I show that $R \circ S = S \circ R$ if $S, R$ are symmetric?

I'm working on a longer proof and this is one of the lemmas I think I need to show, since in general a composition of relations isn't necessarily commutative. I'm struggling with how to use composition in a proof in general so I'm not really sure where to start with this.

Comment: This is not true. If $R$ and $S$ are functions, then $R$ is symmetric iff it is its own inverse, as a function, and we know that composition of functions (even of order $2$) is not commutative. Concretely, take the relations $R=\left\{(1,2),(2,1),(3,3)\right\}$ and $S=\left\{(1,3),(2,2),(3,1)\right\}$ on $\left\{1,2,3\right\}$. Then $R\circ S=\left\{(1,2),(2,3),(3,1)\right\}$ but $S\circ R=\left\{(1,3),(2,1),(3,2)\right\}$.

Comment: @LuizCordeiro make that an answer instead of a comment; you don't really need to add anything either

Comment: @Omnomnomnom You are right. I guess I should write more things as answers instead of comments :p Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true. If $R$ and $S$ are functions, then $R$ is symmetric iff it is its own inverse, as a function, and we know that composition of functions (even of order $2$) is not commutative. Concretely, take the relations $R=\left\{(1,2),(2,1),(3,3)\right\}$ and $S=\left\{(1,3),(2,2),(3,1)\right\}$ on $\left\{1,2,3\right\}$. Then $R\circ S=\left\{(1,2),(2,3),(3,1)\right\}$ but $S\circ R=\left\{(1,3),(2,1),(3,2)\right\}$.

Comment: Oh, my mistake! I guess my proof is heading down the wrong direction then. More specifically I am trying to show $R \circ R^k = R^k \circ R$. (where R^k means it's composed k times) Would that be true?

Comment: @Arjun that holds because composition is **associative**.  In particular, $R \circ R^k = R^{k+1}$ holds by definition, as does $R^k \circ R = R^{k+1}$.

Comment: Oh, I see. Is that essentially breaking it down into $R \circ (R^{k-1} \circ R)$ and regrouping to $R^k \circ R$ with associativity?

Comment: @Arjun yes, that's an equivalent way to look at it.